# Redirect from action to another action in different controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What I want to do is to redirect from an action in "A" controller to an action in "B" controller it gives me this error that it can not find this action in the target controller

I am using `RedirectToAction` Method  any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within your A controller add this in your action

```
RedirectToAction(new {controller="B", action="index", id=11,variable="abc"});
```

that's if you want to send some parameters also ,but do not forget  to have a route configured which can map the "variable" parameter as well. I think this is solved in now

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("kiss", "meoghe");
// RedirectToAction("action name", "controller name"); 
// meogheController => "meoghe" is controller name
```

If you use `ActionResult` for return type on method, you must use `return` for `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the case you've reversed the parameter values in your call to `RedirectToAction` - remember it's `action` first, then `controller`.  Don't forget that `controller` is `"Home"`, too, not `"HomeController"`.

If that still doesn't work - then you've got the action name wrong; or the action you're redirecting to has a filter (e.g. `[HttpPost]`) that's preventing it from being able to be used.

Answer (score -2):

I did this and it worked fine :)

```
  return Redirect("/B/index"); //assuming your controller is called BController.
```

KISS - keep it simple sweetie ;) just pass the url to redirect as string

Comment: Urls may change over time, controllers/views to a lesser extent. It's never a good idea to hardcode values like this.