# How to redirect to another action or route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, actionlink

In my Razor code I have the following action link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("poof", "Poof", new { Id = Model.Id })
```

What I want to happen is that the *Poof* method is invoked but then, I want the computer to navigate to another view - e.g. *Show*.

```
public ActionResult Show(Guid id)
{
  return View(...);
}

public void Poof(Guid id)
{
  ...
  RedirectToRoute("Show", new {Id = id});
  RedirectToAction("Show", new {Id = id});
}
```

I've tried both *RedirectToRoute* and *RedirectToAction* but in both cases, I landed at an empty screen. A closer look at the URL showed that I'm getting stuck at the *.../Poof/...* route instead of being ushered to *.../Show/...* and I can't figure out how to bounce on to the appropriate link.

I'm following something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981061/1525840) but since the break-point in *Show* action isn't hit on (on redirect, that is), I start to wonder if it's more appropriate to play around with route mapping like [this blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asp-net-mvc-redirect-from-one-controller-action-to-another1).

Comment: You should use `*Action` unless you have a specific reason to use `*Route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `Poof` is redirecting to another action, it is still an action itself and as such it needs to return an `ActionResult`. `RedirectToAction` returns an `ActionResult` for just this reason.

```
public ActionResult Poof(Guid id)
{
    // ...

    return RedirectToAction("Show", new {Id = id});
}
```